# Any way to tag a user in a webhook message without knowing the user's actual Slack ID?

Tags: slack-api

I have a Python script that sends out Slack messages using the webhook. The messages includes a user's SSO network login, and I'd like to tag the user in the message. However, since Slack allows a user to change their username, tagging a network ID won't always work. Does Slack have any way of correlating a network login to a username so I can tag them properly?